# Outlook is throwing error when tried to run jscript which creates shell script object to call windows application

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamics-crm, crm, outlook-2010

Below is my jscript code, using which i'm calling my windows application on button click in crm 2011 ribbon. Its working fine in ie.

```
function resume()
{
var _Object=new ActiveXObject( "WScript.Shell" ) ;
_Object.Run("\\\\192.168.0.100\\BackBone_Profile\\winapp\\winapp.exe" );
}
```

When i try to run the same in outlook synchronised with crm its giving error as

[image: Script error]

How to make the application run without any error in outlook.